# Numeric integration over Dirac delta

Tags: numerical-analysis, convergence

I'm trying to solve the following integral numerically.
$$H(y) = \int dx \, f(x) \, \delta(g(x,y)).$$
For this I chose a representation of the delta-function and employ
convergence with respect to $\eta$
$$\sum_\limits{x_i} \, f(x_i) \, \frac{\eta}{g(x_i,y)^2+\eta^2}. $$

I calculate this for every $y$ such that I can plot $H(y)$ in the end.
The problem is, that I would expect for $\eta \rightarrow 0$ the best results, but there seems to be a line (approx. $\eta=10^{-4}$) upon which I get a bunch of delta-like peaks in $H(y)$ instead of a smooth curve (for e.g. $\eta=10^{-2}$) which I want and would expect.

Comment: What about finding the zeroes of $g(x,y)$ rather?

Comment: If its only 1D or 2D, I think I have seen a good algorithm at chebfun.org. For higher dimensional problems, root finding is of course a problem.

Comment: Finding the zero's of g(x,y) requires to do this for every y. One problem is also that you would have to interpolate g, because the x-dependence is known only numerically.
Sounds really complicated procedure to me and I have now idea about stability of this?

Comment: have a look at this example, http://www.chebfun.org/docs/guide/guide14.html

Comment: This approach would require the quadrature method to resolve large changes in function magnitude on length scale of $\eta$, so it's quite reasonable that it fails to do it well when $\eta$ is small. Finding the zeros of $g$ seems like a better approach.

Comment: Is $g$ convex or at least monotonic in $x$?

Comment: I think Joce's proposition is the proper one as well. I believe approximating a Dirac functional cannot be very robust. What do you mean by "x-dependence is known only numerically"? I would assume this means that for each y you have a list of g-values corresponding to some predetermined set of x-values?

Comment: Yes exactly: "for each y you have a list of g-values corresponding to some predetermined set of x-values"

Comment: Then it is probably the most exact, short of using 'chebfun' or spline approximations or similar interpolations, to find the intervals $[a_k,b_k]=[x_j,x_{j+1}]$ with changing signs of the $g$ values from the given  list and add the term $\frac{f(c_k)(b_k-a_k)}{|g(b_k,y)-g(a_k,y)|}$ to the result, where $c_k=\frac{a_kg(b_k,y)-b_kg(a_k,y)}{g(b_k,y)-g(a_k,y)}$ is the estimated root location inside the interval.